# Hacer Ventana De Alerta Más Bonita

Tags: javascript, html, django, funciones, botón

Quisiera convertir esta ventana de alerta, que impide seguir con un evento al pulsar el botón de cancelar, a una ventana más bonita y ojalá con un ícono. He visto que se puede hacer con herramientas como Sweetalert, pero me cuesta entender cómo funciona. ¿No habrá una forma más simple de modificar la ventana?

El evento que se interrumpe es ejecutar una vista de django que elimina un registro de una tabla.

Código del botón rojo que ejecuta la vista de Django correspondiente

```
<p><a href="eliminar1/{{producto.name_prod}}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmar()">Borrar</a></p>
```

Código de la función Javascript

```
function confirmar(){
if (!confirm('¿Desea eliminar el producto?')) {
    alert("El producto no ha sido borrado")
    event.preventDefault();
  }
else{
    alert("El producto ha sido borrado exitosamente")
}
```

}

Y sólo por si a caso, código de la vista de django que se ejecuta cuando se le da "Confirmar" a la ventana de alerta

```
def eliminar1(request, codigo):
cliente=request.user.username
product = Producto.objects.get(name_prod=codigo,client_id=cliente)
product.delete()
return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Que te cuesta entender sobre `sweetalert`?

Comment: La forma en la cual paso lo que ya tengo hecho a su estructura. Puedo hacer algo de 0 con sweetalert, pero por algún motivo me cuesta pasar algo hecho previamente. Tal vez me falta dedicarme, pero mi punto es saber si hay una manera más simple que usar una herramienta amplia como sweetalert

Comment: Creo que lo que pregunta @JoseMgz_Ux es ¿Cuál es tu problema específico con `sweetalert`? Porque si tu pregunta es `saber si hay una manera más simple que usar una herramienta amplia como sweetalert ` creo que es una pregunta basada en opiniones. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example].

Comment: Mira te paso este [codigo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-stonebraker-d07gvr?file=/src/index.js:0-833) no es dificil entender como funciona sweetalert, simplemente copiar y pegar el tipo de alerta que quieres y modificarla a tu antojo

Comment: por ejemplo allí no más la copie y pegue la puse en tu funcion y luego llame a dicha funcion en un boton

Comment: @AndresGardiol Gracias por la recomendación. Sé que podía recorrer esas secciones, pero sólo quería ver si alguien me podía ayudar de manera rápida, y si creían que no era una pregunta adecuada, lo aceptaría, así que está bien lo que me dices.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux Gracias por el ejemplo, se entendió fácilmente!

Comment: Si sigues buscando algo más simple, tal vez te sirva el widget "Dialog" de JQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: @psauleda Muchas gracias por la recomendación